# How to reference embedded SQL Server Reporting Service 2008 images

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, embedded-resource

I have a SQL Server 2008 report with a bit field - **IsUS**

I'd like to display embedded images depending on IsUS bit value.

**How can I *reference* embedded images within a column expression?**

[image]

Below is the result after applying Fillet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706814/how-to-reference-embedded-sql-server-reporting-service-2008-images/3707783#3707783)
-------------------- ***Result*** --------------------

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the "checked" image into the Is US column. Then edit the properties of the image, and set the image expression to:

```
=iif(Fields!IsUS.Value = 1, "checked", "unchecked")
```